# How to use Git for handling two versions of a product

Tags: git

We use Git as source control for development of our commercial desktop software product. We are starting work on a major new version (version 5). Sometimes we'll need to backport some bug fixes in the new version to the current version (version 4).

Back when we used Subversion, we'd make a branch for version 4, keep version 5 in the trunk, and manually apply the relevant bug fixes over time to the version 4 branch. Cumbersome it was. Is this a good approach for Git? If not, what is a good approach?

Comment: What about the [successful git branching model](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/)?

Answer (score 1):

With Git, you'll also use two branches. Git is made to work with branches. They are very lightweight compared to Subversion.

You'll have a branch for each version and probably a development branch. Commits can be easily applied from one branch to another and you can even do hotfix branches.